# HIVE - Cannot partition a table: semantic exception failure

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I'm not able to import data on partitioned table in Hive.

Here is how I create the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS title_ratings
(
tconst STRING,
averageRating DOUBLE,
numVotes INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

And then I load the data into it : `LOAD DATA INPATH '/title.ratings.tsv.gz' INTO TABLE eval_hive_db.title_ratings;`

It works fine till here. Now I want to create a dynamic partitioned table. First of all, I setup theses params:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

I now create my partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS title_ratings_part
(
tconst STRING,
numVotes INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (averageRating DOUBLE)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

insert into title_ratings_part partition(title_ratings) select tconst, averageRating, numVotes from title_ratings;
```

(I also tried with numVotes instead by the way)

And I receive this error: `FAILED: ValidationFailureSemanticException eval_hive_db.title_ratings_part: Partition spec {title_ratings=null} contains non-partition columns`

Someone can help me please?
Ideally, I want to partition my table by averageRating (less than 2, between 2 and 4, and greater than 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to check if there are null values or not.

```
select count(averageRating) from title_ratings group by averageRating;
```

Now, if there are null values in this column then you will get the count, which you have to fill then apply partitioning again.

Comment: I have no null value in my dataset

Answer (score 0):

Partition column is stored as last column in a table so while inserting you need to maintain correct order in select statement.
Pls change order of columns in select.

```
insert into title_ratings_part partition(title_ratings)
Select 
Tconst, 
numVotes, 
averageRating --orderwise this should always be last column
from title_ratings
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. Unfortunally, I have the same issue. Also tried to reorganize entirely my dataset before importing it again to my hdfs. I really don't understand why I can't partition my tables :(

Comment: I am confused. What exactly you're trying to do? Partition existing table or load data from a non partition table to a new partitioned table?

Comment: I'm trying to load data from a non partition table to a new partitioned table.

Comment: Got it.  So above sql should work. Can you pls post what insert sql youre trying and what is the error you got? And pls ensure table structure is same as your original post